# Assigning an aggregate result from select to a user variable in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to save a user variable with a result of count function from a table.

Executing this query:

```
SELECT @var:=count(distinct(column1)) FROM table_name;
```

Returns:

```
@var:=count(distinct(column1))
41243
```

Then executing:

```
SELECT @var;
```

Returns:

```
@var
Blob
```

When I expected 41243.

When I assign a value to a user variable it works as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

---

Edit:
I corrected $var to @var.

I am issuing the query from mySQL Workbench for testing. I will use it eventually from PHP.

Another related question: Can I assign a SELECT result to a user variable without having the result (In my example: 41243) sent back to the client (as it will slow the query if I'm using it from PHP).

Comment: Are you issuing the `SELECT $var;` from PHP by any chance?

Comment: `$var` looks like a `PHP` variable. Show us the code where you're calling this.

Comment: I'm not great with mysql variables, but are you sure you should be using `$var` instead of `@var`? Here's an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec009/3

Comment: Did you mean:

SELECT @var:=count(distinct(column1)) FROM TABLE;

Comment: Added the closing bracket and changed TABLE to table_name

Comment: Are you positive that you are really sending this query (the first one)? Because your output suggests that `@var` contains the value of a BLOB column. Wouldn't you be doing somthing like this instead: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(@var:=column1)) FROM table_name;`. I see the same output as yours with this query (except the column title in the first query) if `table_name.column1` is a `BLOB`.

Comment: I am positive - I think MySQL Workbench might be displaying it improperly as I tried inserting the @val to a temporary table and it seems to get the right value.

Answer (score 2):

You simply have to convert the blob type return value:

```
SELECT @var:=count(distinct(column1)) FROM table1;
SELECT convert(@var,unsigned);
```

Because the result is blob (binary string), you simply have to convert it to integer (in this case unsigned int, but if you use 'signed', then you will get signed integer.

Hope this helps.